# AWS Java SDK v2 not using IRSA IAM Role in EKS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have a small application running in EKS, it has attached a Service Account with an IAM Role (IRSA). When the application tries to send an SQS message it fails with:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied. (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 403
```

My code is:

```
    SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .build();

    sqsClient.sendMessage(SendMessageRequest.builder()
            .queueUrl(queueUrl)
            .messageBody(message)
            .build()
```

I already checked the IAM permissions and they have the correct access and the OIDC trust relationship seems fine. If I enter the pod I can run `aws sts get-caller-identity` and I get the correct role

```
bash-4.4# aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "ASDFSDFSDF:botocore-session-12345678",
    "Account": "123456789",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/eksctl-role/botocore-session-12345678"
}
```

Why is Java not using this role?

Answer (score 4):

When using IAM Roles for Service Accounts (IRSA) the java library authenticates using `WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider` and it requires the `sts` module to work.

[Documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.html)

> Use of this credentials provider requires the 'sts' module to be on the classpath.

Adding the `sts` dependency in my gradle file solved the issue and now it uses the correct IAM role

```
implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.15.0')
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sts'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sqs'
```

Comment: You can probably use `runtimeOnly 'software.amazon.awssdk:sts'`, as you don't need this on the compile-time classpath, only the runtime classpath.